# How to read file having extension .asc in php and it should create array with .mark contained by numeric value?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, codeigniter

```
1.
00:00:00:00
00:00:00:01
Hi

2.
00:00:37:15
00:00:38:16
Hiiii
How Are you?

3.
00:00:40:01
00:00:41:19
Fine.
```

I tried to read above file but I didn't get required result.
I need result in:

```
array(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [asc_id] => 1.
        [start_time] => 00:00:00:00
        [end_time] => 00:00:00:01
        [action_1] => Hi
        [action_2] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [asc_id] => 2.
        [start_time] => 00:00:37:15
        [end_time] => 00:00:38:16
        [action_1] => Hiiii
        [action_2] => How Are you?
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        [asc_id] => 3.
        [start_time] => 00:00:53:02
        [end_time] => 00:00:53:20
        [action_1] => Fine.
        [action_2] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: And what you were getting right now

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: is your file ( the one with data ) saved with extension .asc ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple start, that assumes your input will always be formatted the same as above. There are many improvements you could make to this for error checking and better flexibility on the format of the input.

```
$myarray = array();
$file = file('file.asc');

while ($line = array_shift($file))
{
        if (preg_match('/\d+\.$/', $line))
        {
                $myarray[] = array(
                        'asc_id' => trim($line),
                        'start_time' => trim(array_shift($file)),
                        'end_time' => trim(array_shift($file)),
                        'action_1' => trim(array_shift($file)),
                        'action_2' => trim(array_shift($file)),
                );
        }
}

print_r($myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 'file processing' requirement. Which are:

- read a 'group' of records, 5 in this case
- convert them into an associated array
- append them to a PHP array.

Approach:

- Process the records in groups specified size
- Provide a 'place' for processing the start of the 'group'
- Provide a place for processing the end of the group

As these are 'nested' groups I use a 'read ahead' technique.

[Complete code at pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/PXyw0MrK)

'long-winded'? maybe :)

The code:

Data definitions:

```
/**
 * Data definition
 */
define('SOURCE_FILE', __DIR__ . '/Q31609517-data.asc');
define('MAX_LINE_LEN', 128);

// data group details
define ('DATA_GROUP_SIZE', 5);

// allow easy changing of data names and changing the input order
$itemNames = array('asc_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'action_1', 'action_2');
```

Process the data:

```
/**
 * Process the file
 */
$sourceFile = fopen(SOURCE_FILE, 'r');

$currentLine = fgets($sourceFile, MAX_LINE_LEN); // always use 'read ahead';

// process the file
while (!feof($sourceFile) && $currentLine !== false) {

    // start group processing
    $currentGroupLine = 0;
    $currentGroup = array();

    while ($currentGroupLine < DATA_GROUP_SIZE) {

        $currentGroup[$itemNames[$currentGroupLine]] = trim($currentLine);
        $currentGroupLine++;

        $currentLine = fgets($sourceFile, MAX_LINE_LEN); // always use 'read ahead';
    }

    // process complete group
    $outData[] = $currentGroup;
}

fclose($sourceFile);
```

The test data (5 lines per group):

```
1.
00:00:00:00
00:00:00:01
Hi

2.
00:00:37:15
00:00:38:16
Hiiii
How Are you?
3.
00:00:40:01
00:00:41:19
Fine.
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [asc_id] => 1.
            [start_time] => 00:00:00:00
            [end_time] => 00:00:00:01
            [action_1] => Hi
            [action_2] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [asc_id] => 2.
            [start_time] => 00:00:37:15
            [end_time] => 00:00:38:16
            [action_1] => Hiiii
            [action_2] => How Are you?
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [asc_id] => 3.
            [start_time] => 00:00:40:01
            [end_time] => 00:00:41:19
            [action_1] => Fine.
            [action_2] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: I trim the input, when storing it, as it has `whitespace` in it which will confuse 'things.